# Fire a NotBlank validation depeding on another field

Tags: symfony

I have a symfony form where i need to fire an `@Assert\NotBlank` only if `$receiverNewsletter` if not Blank.

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @Assert\NotBlank
 * @Assert\Email
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=190)
 */
private $email;


/**
 * @var bool
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="receiveNewsletter", type="boolean")
 */
private $receiveNewsletter;
```

A part of my form:

```
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('receiveNewsletter', CheckboxType::class, ['label' => 'form.label.receiveNewsletter'])
            ->add('email', EmailType::class, ['label' => 'form.label.email', 'required' => false])
}
```

Any idea how to use payload to say if receiveNewsletter not null then fire the NotBlank validation on email field?

Comment: you can use form events in this case. check this link https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Expression`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Expression.html) constraint for this particular functionality. It does not use `NotBlank` specifically but I find it more elegant solution.

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @Assert\Expression(
 *     "(this.getReceiveNewsletter() and this.getEmail()) or !this.getReceiveNewsletter()",
 *     message="Email cannot be empty when Receive Newsletter is marked"
 * )
 */
class Entity
{
...
}
```

You put constraint on a whole entity and it evaluates the expression according to [expression syntax](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/expression_language/syntax.html).

Comment: What about translation is it possible to use @AssertBlank with  to get translated validation message without making any effort ?

Comment: not sure about that, but i just noticed the flaw in my expression

Comment: i updated an expression a bit, it needs to evaluate as true to have mark entity as valid, so now it checks if both `receiveNewsletter` and `email` are present, or `receiveNewsletter` is not present

Comment: and I suppose for translation you need to provide your own translated string for `message` parameter